# itimer expiration

Tags: c, timer, linux-kernel

I was using a periodic timer and taking times between when two `SIGALRM` signals are received. what I observed was that `itimer` might expires a little before or little after the time I set. e.g. if I set it for `1m sec` , it might expires at `0.9998msec` or `1.0023msec`.

Shouldn't the timer expiration would always be greater than what is set? less time taken is what I dont understand.

here's my code:

```
enter code here     
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define INTERVAL 1000


struct timespec ti[100];
int s=0;


void ex(int i)
{int d=0;
struct timespec t[100],s1,s2;
   for(d=0;d<99;d++)
    {
    s1= ti[d];
    s2= ti[d+1];
   printf("%u:%u\t%u:%u\t", s1.tv_sec, s1.tv_nsec, s2.tv_sec, s2.tv_nsec);

    if ((s2.tv_nsec- s1.tv_nsec)<0) {
        t[d].tv_sec = s2.tv_sec-s1.tv_sec-1;
        t[d].tv_nsec = 1000000000 +s2.tv_nsec -s1.tv_nsec;
    } else {
        t[d].tv_sec = s2.tv_sec-s1.tv_sec;
        t[d].tv_nsec = s2.tv_nsec-s1.tv_nsec;
    }

    printf("%u:%u\n",t[d].tv_sec,t[d].tv_nsec);  

    } 
   exit(0);
}

void alarm_wakeup (int i)
{  
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ti[s]); 
    s++;
    if(s==100)
    { ex(0);
    }
}


void main ()
{
  struct itimerval tout_val;
  tout_val.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
  tout_val.it_interval.tv_usec = INTERVAL;
  tout_val.it_value.tv_sec = 0; 
  tout_val.it_value.tv_usec = INTERVAL;


  setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &tout_val,0);

  signal(SIGALRM,alarm_wakeup); /* set the Alarm signal capture */
 signal(SIGINT,ex);

  while (1)
{ 
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the timer expires, the signal is raised and the timer is rescheduled.

However, there can be a delay between the signal being raised and the signal being handled - if the process isn't running already, it has to be rescheduled.  This means that there is a potentially variable delay between the actual expiration of the timer and when the `clock_gettime()` call in your signal handler runs.

If this delay before the `clock_gettime()` call is higher one iteration than the next, then the time between the `clock_gettime()` calls will be slightly less than 1ms even though there was a 1ms gap between the subsequent timer expiries.

In diagrammatic form:

```
time:                0ms...............1ms...............2ms...............3ms
timer expiry:        X                 X                 X                 X
signal handler runs:  S                      S            S                  S
```

You can see that the longer delay before the second signal handler ran made the third signal appear to be "early", even though the underlying timer was not.

Comment: First thanks for replying @caf .. so, what i understood is that the measurements less than the time interval are due to the fact my handler is running a bit late. when i was running this program the system was very lightly loaded and still i m getting these variations. if my system gets highly loaded, my handler would possibly be scheduled with even more uncertainty causing more variations. right?     secondly is this possible that kernel itself can expire the timer a little before the time?

Comment: one more question.... :D..... can the expiry time (the X marks in ur diagram) be late in a loaded system?

Comment: @tulips6: Yes, the variation will tend to be more if you system is more highly loaded.  If you put your process in a real-time priority class then this should be reduced.  The expiry times can't be early.  They can be late, but the next expiry time is always calculated from when the timer *should* have expired.

Comment: what do u think about this link... (http://lwn.net/Articles/461592/) how can i know a particular feature is added in kernel or not?

Comment: @tulips6: That article refers to in-kernel timers, I don't think range timers are exposed to userspace.

Comment: can u suggest any compact reading material for in-kernel timer? becoz i dont know about them i detail. i was thinking that i m using hrtimer by using setitimer() function. these timers can be created and destroyed from user space. is there a difference between interval timer and range timer.?